# weird issue when sorting MySQL `date` results

Tags: mysql, date, sorting

I'm getting some weird results when I query on of my tables to show upcoming birthdays (schema and query below), and then sort by date with the upcoming dates first. The type for the `dob` (date of birth) field is `date` with the format `0000-00-00`

I'm using the below schema:

```
People:
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| fname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| lname      | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| dob        | date        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00        |                |
| license_no | varchar(24) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| date_added | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| status     | varchar(8)  | NO   |     | Allow             |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

and here's my query, as it's called from PHP:

```
<?php   
/* This will give us upcoming dobs for the next 2 weeks */
$con = connect_db();
// grab any dobs coming up in the next week and sort them by what's 
//coming up first
//if they are born on Feb. 29th, it will fall on March 1st
$query = 'select p.lname, p.fname, u.number, p.dob ' . 
         'from people p, units u where p.id = u.resident and ' .
         'DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(dob, INTERVAL ' .
         '(YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(dob)) YEAR)) AND DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) +30 >= ' .
         'dayofyear(`dob`) order by dayofyear(dob) limit 7;';

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
if (!empty($result)) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                $fname = $row['fname'];
                $lname = $row['lname'];
                $number = $row['number'];
                $dob = date("m-d", strtotime($row['dob']));
                if($dob == date("m-d")) {
                        $dob = 'Today!';
                        printf('%s, %s</br>Unit: %s</br>%s</br></br>', $lname, 
                               $fname, $number, $dob);
                } else {
                       printf('%s, %s</br>Unit: %s</br>Date: %s</br></br>', $lname,
                              $fname, $number, $dob);
                }       
        }       
 }       
?>
```

here's an example of the returned query:

```
Name, Name
Unit: 110
Date: 09-11

Name2, Name2
Unit: 434
Date: 09-10
```

As you can see, the order is wrong!

EDIT - Now I've noticed that the records in question (the two dates above) are not ordered correctly *ever* in MySQL!

One of the full dates is: `1950-09-11`
and the other is: `1956-09-10`

I've looked through those two records and haven't found any mangled data, so I'm pretty confused as to why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY dayofyear(dob) ASC

Good luck

Comment: ASC is default value of ORDER BY. It can be omitted.